# How to I serve the static HTML file at the root directory in a wordpress site?

Tags: htaccess, react, headless

I am trying to use wordpress as a headless CMS for my react frontend. The build version is completely functional connecting to the wordpress api `https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2`. The react production files are deployed to a subdomain `https://www.app.example.com/` and the main domain `https://www.example.com/` is now redirected to the above site. But I want to host both the front end and wordpress backend on the same domain `https://www.example.com/`

I tried removing the redirect and editing the `.htaccess` file to point the root directory to where the react build version is hosted on the server (`/app/dist` from the root of website). Here is what I have tried.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/dist/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But still the default wordpress homepage is being shown on visiting the `https://www.example.com/`. How can I point the all routes to `/app/dist/index.html` file except `/wp-admin` route?

Appreciate your time, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing - a 'landing' page at the root site that was custom-built (via PHP), but then WordPress-based pages elsewhere.

I did it with the htaccess file for the site:

```
# For example.com root, set landing.php as the default page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /landing.php [L]
```

This will redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to [www.example.com/landing.php](http://www.example.com/landing.php) . All other pages will use the normal WP htaccess rules (positioned after the above directives).

I also have these directive above to force HTTPS:

```
# Force all requests to use HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Rick. I am looking for a way to have my react production build - an index.html file to be served when a user visits `www.example.com` without any redirection. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Don't do React. The technique shown above works fine to show a non-WordPress landing page on a site that uses WP for all other pages. The redirection is not noticeable to the visitor - the browser URL still shows as example.com .

Comment: This seems exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the solution. Just one problem, I can't access the `/wp-json` route now. It returns a 404 error. How to fix that?

Comment: Dunno why wp-json route doesn't work. Assume that you commented out the home page redirect and then wp-json worked? If not, then perhaps a directive the rest of the htaccess file is causing problems. 
(It's 'good form' to mark the answer as 'correct' if it worked for you. Helps me and others that might wander by.)